# Getting input value from a data attribute

Tags: javascript, html, input, onchange

I have this code below where user can choose - each dropdown option has different data-tenure:

```
<div class="ten columns">
  <p class="slider-label">Loan Tenure (Years)</p>
  <!-- <input type="text" class="loan-tenure numeric-only" /> -->
  <div class="field">
    <div class="picker picker-dd2">
      <select class="dropdown2 loan-tenure">
        <option class="dropdown2-opt" data-tenure=“0.0298” value="1">1</option>
        <option class="dropdown2-opt" data-tenure=“0.0387” value="2">2</option>
        <option class="dropdown2-opt" data-tenure=“0.0418” value="3">3</option>
        <option class="dropdown2-opt" data-tenure=“0.0434” value="4">4</option>
        <option class="dropdown2-opt" data-tenure=“0.0444” value="5">5</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want is to set the input value to the data-tenure above - :

```
                <input type="hidden" class="loan-rate" value="??" />
```

Do I need to add onchange() function to the dropdown above?

Comment: have you tried anything? plz paste the code u tried..

Comment: Hi rory-h can u please tell me what does the select attribute "data-tenure" does or stands for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code. Here we are passing the object via an onchange event.

```
<div class="ten columns">
  <p class="slider-label">Loan Tenure (Years)</p>
  <!-- <input type="text" class="loan-tenure numeric-only" /> -->
  <div class="field">
    <div class="picker picker-dd2">
      <select onchange="tenure_rates(this)" class="dropdown2 loan-tenure">
        <option class="dropdown2-opt" data-tenure=“0.0298” value="1">1</option>
        <option class="dropdown2-opt" data-tenure=“0.0387” value="2">2</option>
        <option class="dropdown2-opt" data-tenure=“0.0418” value="3">3</option>
        <option class="dropdown2-opt" data-tenure=“0.0434” value="4">4</option>
        <option class="dropdown2-opt" data-tenure=“0.0444” value="5">5</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function tenure_rates(dropdownValue) {
       $('.dropdown2-opt').data('tenure',dropdownValue.value);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit, Updated

> I meant - getting the data-tenure and this will be the input value. So
>   if the user selects 1, the input value will be 0.0298. If the user
>   selects 2 the input value will be 0.0387

You can use `change` event at `.dropdown2` element,  `document.querySelector()` with selector `"input.loan-rate"`, set `.value` property with `event.target` `Element.dataset` at `change` event handler

```
document.querySelector(".dropdown2").addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  // set value here   
  document.querySelector("input.loan-rate")
  .value = event.target.dataset.tenure; 
})
```

Comment: Sorry I meant - getting the data-tenure and this will be the input value. So if the user selects 1, the input value will be 0.0298. If the user selects 2 the input value will be 0.0387..and so.

Comment: @rory-h _"I meant - getting the data-tenure and this will be the input value. So if the user selects 1, the input value will be 0.0298. If the user selects 2 the input value will be 0.0387"_ To set `.value` of element substitute `document.querySelector("input.loan-rate")
  .value = event.target.dataset.tenure` for `document.querySelector("input.loan-rate")
  .dataset.tenure = event.target.dataset.tenure`. See updated post

Answer (score 1):

```
 <select class="dropdown2 loan-tenure" id="selectId">
    <option class="dropdown2-opt" data-tenure=“0.0298” value="1">1</option>
    <option class="dropdown2-opt" data-tenure=“0.0387” value="2">2</option>
    <option class="dropdown2-opt" data-tenure=“0.0418” value="3">3</option>
    <option class="dropdown2-opt" data-tenure=“0.0434” value="4">4</option>
    <option class="dropdown2-opt" data-tenure=“0.0444” value="5">5</option>
  </select>

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#selectId").change(function(){
     alert($("#selectId option:selected").attr("data-tenure"));
      alert($("#selectId").val());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use select tag to take input

```
<select name="" form="tenureform">
  <option value="">1</option>
  <option value="">2</option>
  <option value="">3</option>
  <option value="">4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select onchange="changeInput()" class="dropdown2 loan-tenure">
        <option class="dropdown2-opt" data-tenure=“0.0298” value="1">1</option>
        <option class="dropdown2-opt" data-tenure=“0.0387” value="2">2</option>
        <option class="dropdown2-opt" data-tenure=“0.0418” value="3">3</option>
        <option class="dropdown2-opt" data-tenure=“0.0434” value="4">4</option>
        <option class="dropdown2-opt" data-tenure=“0.0444” value="5">5</option>
      </select>

function onChange(evt) {
    document.querySelector("input.loan-rate").dataset.tenure = evt.currentTarget.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a vanilla js solution. There will probably be tons of jquery responses. You do need the onchange event:

```
<select class="dropdown2 loan-tenure" onchange="document.getElementById('loanrate').value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].dataset.tenure">
```

Make sure you add the id 'loadrate' to your input. [See it in action here](https://jsfiddle.net/ff8jrx50/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `selectedIndex` to get the the current selected option. Then use `getAttribute`to get the `data-tenure` attribute value.Use `getElementsByClassName` to select the hidden input element and set it's value.

```
function tenure_rates(){
var e = document.getElementById("dropdown2");
var _option = e.options[e.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-tenure');
document.getElementsByClassName('loan-rate')[0].value = _option;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/2fsLwwky/)

Note: Initially the value of hidden field will always be empty,since `1` is pre selected. So if an user don't change the option you will never find any value set this hidden element. You can select an option like `Select`

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div class="ten columns">
    <input type="hidden" class="loan-rate" value="" />
  <p class="slider-label">Loan Tenure (Years)</p>
  <!-- <input type="text" class="loan-tenure numeric-only" /> -->
  <div class="field">
    <div class="picker picker-dd2">
      <select class="dropdown2 loan-tenure">
        <option class="dropdown2-opt" data-tenure=“0.0298” value="1">1</option>
        <option class="dropdown2-opt" data-tenure=“0.0387” value="2">2</option>
        <option class="dropdown2-opt" data-tenure=“0.0418” value="3">3</option>
        <option class="dropdown2-opt" data-tenure=“0.0434” value="4">4</option>
        <option class="dropdown2-opt" data-tenure=“0.0444” value="5">5</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <script>
        var sel = document.querySelector(".loan-tenure");
        var hidEle = document.querySelector(".loan-rate");
        sel.onchange = function(){
            var value = sel.value;
            hidEle.setAttribute("value",value);
            alert("Input hidden value is : " + hidEle.getAttribute("value"));
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```